# backpage button with javascript

Tags: javascript, .net

I have a aspnet application where I have a validation on a dropdownlist if more than one item is selected when user press a button a javascript messa apper saying "hey you need to choice only one item", then user choose onlyone item and navigate to next page.

If the user press back button on navigate the message from `javacript` apper again and I don't want it.

How to handle it?

Here my javascript if he choice 2 items on **dropdownlist**

```
Response.Write("<script LANGUAGE= 'JavaScript'> alert ('Selecione 1 contrato para consultar ou adicionar suplementação de verba')</script>");
```

here if he choise onlyone item

```
Response.Redirect(string.Format("xxxx.aspx?id={0}&idContrato={1}", Request.QueryString["id"], idContrato.ToString()));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.Net DropDownList controls only allow for one selection. If you have some default value (Say, 'Select one...' with a value of -1) then you can do JavaScript validation to ensure that value isn't the one being submitted, as follows:

```
function checkDropDown() {
    var e = document.getElementById("<%= DropDownList1.ClientID %>");
    if(e.options[e.selectedIndex].value == -1) { 
        alert("Please select an option");
        return false;
    }
    else { return true; }
}
```

This function can then be placed in the onClick event of your Submit button during the Page_Load event in ASP.Net as follows:

```
SubmitButton.Attributes.Add("onClick","return checkDropDown();")
```